# Mongodb Java add new array element in document

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm using mongo 2.2.3 and the java driver. My dilemma, I have to $push a field and value into an array element, but I cant seem to figure out how to do this. A sample of my data:

```
"_id" : 1,
"scores" : [
    {
        "type" : "english",
        "score" : 78.97979
    },
    {
        "type" : "spanish",
        "score" : 6.99
    }
]
```

I want to push one array `attribute ("grade" : "A")` in document where `type = english`.

after push document look like this :

```
"_id" : 1,
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "english",
            "score" : 78.97979,
            "grade" : "A"
        },
        {
            "type" : "spanish",
            "score" : 6.99
        }
    ]
```

I tried using shell :

```
db.Sample.update({"scores.type" : "english"},{"$push" : {"scores": {"grade":"A"}}})
```

But this is not adding attribute on specific position.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @gasparms, Yes, i tried and solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this update with [Set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and reference:

```
db.Sample.update({"scores.type" : "english"},{"$set" : {"scores.$.grade":"A"}})
```

Comment: Hello, @gasparms can you differentiate $set and $push ??

Comment: Maybe you want to know differences between $push and $addToSet? Becasue, $set and $push are totally differentes.  $set replace the value of field and $push append a value to an array.